# Importing MICE object to Stata for analysis

Tags: r, import, export, stata, r-mice

I am trying to use imputed data created with MICE in Stata.

My understanding of the steps are:

1) converting the mids object to mi in R

```
 m=20
 completed=lapply(1:20,function(i)complete(imp,i))
 completed.mi=do.call(Zelig::mi,completed)
```

2)   preparing mice object for exporting in R

(a) mi2stata

```
 STATA=mi::mi2stata(completed.mi, m=20, file="C:\\Users\\STATA.csv", 
 missing.ind = FALSE)
 Note: after loading the data into Stata, version 11 or later, type 'mi 
 import ice' to register the data as being multiply imputed. 
 For Stata 10 and earlier, install MIM by typing 'findit mim' and include 
 'mim:' as a prefix for any command using the MI data.
 Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
 trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "mi") that is not an S4 
 object
```

(b) Following the suggestion from below to write a csv without mi2stata:

```
   data_out <- data.table::rbindlist(completed, idcol="m")
   write.csv(data_out, "C:\\deleted\\STATA2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

3) importing the CSV file of the original, nonimputed data into Stata

**appears to have worked fine. all variables from CSV file appears on the 
     right-hand side

4) use mi import ice command in Stata

(a) error re: mi2stata (I had actually imported the non-imputed file)

```
. mi import ice STATA
varlist not allowed
r(101);
```

(b) error in reading CSV version of imputed data

```
 mi import ice[stata2]
 weights not allowed
 r(101);
```

I have encountered errors with 2, 4, and possibly 1 (as error for 2 refers back to conversion of mice object to mi class data). I would really appreciate a user friendly step by step guidance. Although mi2stata might not work directly work for mice objects, I am still interested in learning a solution for this.

Comment: The error for Q3 has now been resolved and is not occurring sporadically. If important piece of information is needed, please let me know. Importing specific imputed object from R is the core of my question and as you suggest response from an R & Stata user is desired.

Comment: The important information that would be helpful is an MCVE. As I am not an R user I can't be more specific on whether something less than that would be enough to allow a good answer.

Comment: you can't use `mi::mi2stata` with the data that results from `Zelig::mi`. Could you export them as csv's and then read in to stata? (I don't have stata so don't know what format it requires)

Comment: a quick example to see if it works. .. `library(mice);
 imp = mice(nhanes, m=2, print=FALSE);
 completed <- lapply(seq_len(imp$m),function(i) complete(imp,i));
 data_out <- data.table::rbindlist(completed, idcol="m");
 write.csv(data_out, "stata.csv", row.names=FALSE)` . Perhaps this is enough for you to tweak to the correct format that stata requires. perhaps @NickCox can help with this.

Comment: actaully. this seems more inline with what mi2stata does: `completed <- lapply(seq_len(imp$m),function(i) complete(imp,i)) ; 
 data_out <- data.table::rbindlist(completed, idcol="_mi") ; 
 data_out <- rbind(nhanes, data_out, fill=TRUE) ; 
 data_out[, "_mi" := replace(`_mi`, is.na(`_mi`), 0)] ; 
 data_out[, "_mj" := .I, by="_mi"] ; 
 write.csv(data_out, "stata.csv", row.names=FALSE)` , but I dont know if these additional steps are required)

Comment: converting the mice imputed data into the "mi class" object appears to be the major problem here. Accordig to R documentation: mi2stata(imputations, m, file, missing.ind=FALSE, ...). Using "completed" or "data_out" leads to the following error: imputations must be an object of class 'mi'

Comment: the above error is different from one that results from data that zelig::mi generated (Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "mi") that is not an S4 obj)

Comment: @ksroogl ; exactly. You can't use mi::mi2stata on that data - you just can't!. A quick look at the function shows it tries to extract using `@`, ie S4 class, which your completed data is not of this type. Shouldn't be too hard to write your own. Try tweaking the code in the above comments.

Comment: Right, "completed" "data_out" were obtained from the code you provided in the comments. completed <- lapply(seq_len(imp$m),function(i) complete(imp,i)). I wasn't quite sure whether "completed" or "data_out" should go into "imputations" and tried both

Comment: resulting error was hat neither of those were object of class 'mi'

Comment: neither. The code in the comments is to prepare the data to go into stata. (i wrote it out as a csv, but you could use foreign::write.dta). So you don't need to use mi2stata. I am not sure of what stata requires, but the above code may need tweaked.

Comment: got it. didn't recognize that the suggestion was to prepare a stata-ready dataset not involving mi2stata command

Comment: @ksroogl ; re your edit: Try the code in my [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965155/importing-mice-object-to-stata-for-analysis#comment86947560_49965155) - the one with the variables `_mi`, and `_mj`. And read the stata docs ie https://www.stata.com/manuals13/mimiimportice.pdf , to make sure the data you write out is in the correct format.#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collecting the comments above: you can't use `mi::mi2stata` with either the data that results from `Zelig::mi` or from `mice::complete`. But if you look at the code for `mi::mi2stata`, it just seems to stack the raw data, and each imputed dataset. It then adds indices to mark each dataset, and each observation.

```
library(mice)
# don't really need data.table but makes adding the indices easier
library(data.table) 

# Function to export mice imputed datasets
mice2stata <- function(imp, path="stata", type="dta"){ 

          completed <- lapply(seq_len(imp$m),function(i) complete(imp,i))     
          data_out <- rbindlist(completed, idcol="_mj")     
          data_out <- rbind(imp$data, data_out, fill=TRUE)     
          data_out[, `_mj` := replace(`_mj`, is.na(`_mj`), 0L)]     
          data_out[, `_mi` := rowid(`_mj`)]     
          if(type=="dta") {

              foreign::write.dta(data_out, file=paste(path, type, sep="."))             

          } else {

              write.csv(data_out, file=paste(path, type, sep="."), na="", row.names=FALSE)
          }

    }
```

An example

```
imp <- mice(nhanes, m=2, print=FALSE) 
mice2stata(imp, type="dta")
```

Then in Stata use

```
use path\to\stata.dta 
mi import ice
```

Answer (score 2):

Q4 looks straightforward. The syntax for that command (**not** function) is documented as

```
   mi import ice [, options]
```

and so `STATA` looks like an attempt to specify a variable list. Where does that come from?

If Q2 failed, was the point of Q3 and Q4?

I hope that some R user can add some comments on Q2. On the face of it, you got an explicit error message, so do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Q3 actually appears to have worked fine. Non-imputed data was saved as a CSV file, which does include the names of all variables. Edits made to the question to reflect changes that have occurred since the initial attempt. I am not a stata user so messages it generates are not straightforward to me

Comment: If this procedure works sometimes and not others, then we need extra information to find out what's going on. I am most unlikely to be able to add to the single point above as I don't use R routinely or multiple imputation ever.

Comment: In Stata new users as well as more experienced ones should look at the `help` for a command. The help here gives no signal that the word `STATA` is ever needed or even allowed. The error message isn't self-explanatory here but in essence Stata can't work out what you want from illegal syntax. It's guessing. Its guess is based on your typing something before the comma that looks like a variable name where no such variable name is allowed.